# update submodule with latest commit #

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-submodules

Here is my **repo A** with submodule:

[image]

[image]

Here is my **repo B** that is used as a submodule in the other repo A:

[image]

Each time when there is a new commit in **repo B**:

[image]

I run the following commands in **repo A** to update the commit # in submodule:

```
git submodule update --remote --merge
git add *
git commit -m “updated public submodule”
git push
```

Then I create a Pull Request in **repo A** to update this commit # in submodule.

[image]

Is there an alternate/automated approach to update the commit  # in submodule instead of creating PR?

UPDATE:

Bothe are ADO repositories.

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text. Just post the text as text.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to do some automation on the submodule update on Repo A.
There are multiple ways to answer this:

- To automatically create Pull Requests on Repo A, you could use https://dependabot.com/ - I guess this is what your are looking for.
- You may do this on your own with any CI tool (Jenkins, Github Actions...) quite easily.